# Is there a "Northwind" type database available for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, northwind

I need some test data for a MySQL utility that I am creating.  Does anybody know where I can find one that has a similiar (if not more) amount of data as Northwind for SQL Server?

Comment: And yes... I tried Googling for "mysql test database"... (rolls eyes)

Comment: I use a WordPress database and populate with dummy instead.

Comment: @rock I would prefer a more business-related schema, with dollar amounts, percentages, averages, etc.  And of course, I don't have the time (nor the patience) to manually populate.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

This is an answer for about 4 years ago and links were dead because of time, I'll put new links as soon as I find some.

---

1- [FlightStats](http://dl.flightstats.us/)

2- [MySql Version of NW schema (InnoDB)](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/mysqlbook/sampler/mysqled1_appe.html)

3- [MySql Version of NW schema (MyISAM)](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/mysqlbook/sampler/mysqled1_appe.html#11-2)

4- [more info](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/187103)

and a suggestion from mindplay.dk:

5- [Northwind](http://marakana.com/download/sql/northwind.sql) (schema+data, as provided by mnk below)

Comment: The FlightStats link seems to be dead. Anywhere else where it can be found?

Comment: @NickJ This answer for about 4 years ago. I'll find new links asap.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a version of Northwind for MySQL on GitHub.  The column names have been slightly altered to fit the MySQL standard.

https://github.com/dalers/mywind

Answer (score 5):

You may download it from here:
http://dev.wavemaker.com/forums/?q=node/4721

Comment: Link is dead...

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to export the actual Northwind DB to MySQL. http://www.geeksengine.com/article/export-access-to-mysql.html

FlightStats seems to be another one you could use: http://flightstats.us/about.php

> The purpose of this application is to demonstrate MySQL 4.1 and some of its new and more advanced features. As MySQL matures, it is the hope that this application will also mature. Currently, the following features are used in some meaningful way:
>
> - Joins
> - Subqueries
> - Subqueries in the FROM clause
> - Query cache

Answer (score 3):

I have tested quite all the dumps available in this thread with latest MariaDB but all of them were returning warnings or errors

searching out there I have found this

http://www.dotnettwitter.com/2011/05/northwind-database-scripts-for-sql.html

**UPDATED LINK** https://www.zentut.com/sql-tutorial/sql-sample-database/ (see at bottom)

**ANOTHER LINK** https://www.sourcecodester.com/sql/12809/3-sql-version-northwind-database.html (use blue download button in the page)

so far this is the unique **Northwind for MariaDB MySQL** that works like a charm

no errors, no warnings,

I link it since it is not listed in this thread

Comment: I too have had a number of issues with the other DBs in the the other answers, so I was hoping that this dump would work. However, unfortunately, the link seems to be dead?

Comment: Added an updated link. Please remeber to vote

Comment: The new link is the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32144302/4424636). Is that the DB that the original links pointed to? I've found that the MyWInd doesn't exactly match the NorthWind DB, at least not the same as the DB used in [these w3Schools examples](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_syntax.asp), although I'm starting to think that maybe those examples are out of date anyway.

Comment: @Greenonline see new link, and remember to vote

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Can be [found here](https://code.google.com/p/northwindextended/downloads/detail?name=Northwind.MySQL5.sql), for instance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a sample database provided by MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/index.html

Answer (score 0):

There's a link at the beginning of the article where you can grab an `SQL` script with structure and data:

http://www.geeksengine.com/article/export-access-to-mysql.html

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is from a long time ago, but I needed specifically Northwind on MySQL a while ago. So I migrated the structure and data on [the current version of Northwind in Codeplex](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=northwinddatabase) to MySQL.

In case anyone else needs it, [it can be found here](https://bitbucket.org/fahedsl/notwind/src)

Comment: The second link is dead