# Public SQL database for educational purposes

Tags: sql, jdbc

I am looking for a publicly available SQL database with free access, where one can run some `SELECT` queries for free on some meaningful data (not item1, item2, item3). Have you seen any? Even better if it came together with some tutorial.

Vendor is not that relevant, as long as one can connect using a generic JDBC client.

Comment: Do you mean a hosted version or something that you host yourself?

Comment: A hosted solution is preferred, but I will go for self-hosting as a second choice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [SQL Exercises](http://www.sql-ex.com/)

Start with [learning stage](http://www.sql-ex.com/learn_exercises.php)

Comment: I like this one. This even exceeds my expectations although JDBC connectivity is not provided. I believe their web interface is enough.

Comment: That's a fab site, @msi77. I just worked my way through all the learning exercises, and my brain hurts a bit now :)

Comment: Matt Gibson - Somebody called it as drug, but I, nevertheless, invite you to the rating stages.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

If SQL Server is an option then Northwind/Adventureworks are the standard "training" DBs. Do a search.

For mySql this project looks promising:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/awmysql/

Also, this might be a dupe:

[Is there a "Northwind" type database available for MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036395/is-there-a-northwind-type-database-available-for-mysql)

[Where can I download Northwind database for Postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585643/where-can-i-download-northwind-database-for-postgresql)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest setting up Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express (or the R2), and adding the [Northwind or Adventureworks](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/) database. It's pretty big so I'm sure you can play with it.

Answer (score 2):

I found [SQLZoo](http://sqlzoo.net) which is something similar too.

Comment: Exactly. Go to http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_basics and in any field enter "show tables" and you can see all tables. Now hit something like "select * from album" and you can see some data. This is amazing - public database to test skills :))))

Answer (score 2):

You can use 
https://db4free.net/
which allows you to access it remotely from your code or tools like JMeter.

It's slow but works.

it requires registration.

Answer (score 1):

If you're intersted, Eve Online, a rather large MMO, make their static data (in-game items, NPCs, anything that doesn't really change) available via download.

***edit:* http://www.eveonline.com/community/toolkit.asp

It's a very heavily normalized data set, with over a dozen table, and thousands of records.
If you want to dive into the deep end of enterprise data warehousing, I'd recommend this.

Downloads as a MS SQL Server 2008 Backup file, which can be imported directly into MS SQL Server 2008 Express (The free edition)

I do not recommend this if you are brand new to databasing, however.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to ask your government for some statistical data (just browse their website; there should be plenty). Then import the data in a [H2 database](http://www.h2database.com/) and import it. Save the resulting DB files somewhere and give them to your students for their work.

Answer (score 0):

I like the concept of a game on pure SQL as implemented here: https://mystery.knightlab.com
It offers gamification of learning SQL and includes an optional tutorial-like introduction.
If you already know SQL but feel a little rusty, then this is fun to brush up.
For beginners it is an easy hand-help first contact.

The data are artificial and have a slightly steep drop-off when leaving the immediate game track, but I think it still matchs your requirement to be "meaningful". (And if you go intentionally off-track, then there are hints that some easter-eggs can be found, in the shape of jokes. I did not yet manage to get the query right to actually read them... So I think that even beyond the obvious game there is something for the more experienced to hunt for.)

Comment: Note, I think the question could be considered off-topic, but still like it and the answers. So I decided to join in contributing another answer, following the existing examples.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the AWS RDS service. Create a Cloud-based database there, obtain your credentials and share them to public.