# Ready web query interface to SQL databases

Tags: sql, database, web-applications, rdbms

Do you know any free tool which would constitute a **web-based SQL database generic query interface**, incl.:

- (mainly) allowing to type in an SQL query and display the result in some nice way
- the interface should allow for some basic security - allowing only `SELECT` queries
- the very need is to support MS SQL Server, but Oracle support would be useful
- should run against an existing database instance without any re-configuration needed
- might be simple, no need to browse tables, analyze database columns or anything else you would experience in SQLDeveloper or SQL Server Management Studio

Platform / language / etc. is of second importance.

Comment: [SQLPad](http://rickbergfalk.github.io/sqlpad/) seems to fit the bill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Re:dash (Redash)](http://redash.io/) is a promising new open-source player on the market. From their own website:

> re:dash is our take on freeing the data within our company in a way
>   that will better fit our culture and usage patterns.
>
> Prior to re:dash, we tried to use traditional BI suites and discovered
>   a set of bloated, technically challenged and slow tools/flows. What we
>   were looking for was a more hacker'ish way to look at data, so we
>   built one.

Answer (score 4):

The [StackExchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) has this functionality ([example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/466/most-controversial-posts-on-the-site)) and it is [open source](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer), so you may be able to just install and make use of it, or even extract the relevant code.

Comment: Ah, great. I have used SEDE in the past, but I didn't know it's open source. (I hope it's quite simple to start it, I have no experience in .NET). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something like the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Obviously, this is mainly for demonstration purposes - it won't help you if you want to install it on top of your own database.

Comment: Thanks for the mention, Branko.  I think SQL Fiddle (my site, btw) fits OP's description quite well.

Comment: My intention was to run it against an existing database, which I don't have control of. And to display data from it. So although SQL Fiddle looks great it wasn't the thing I was after.

Comment: But quite by accident SQL Fiddle seems to match my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911161/public-sql-database-for-educational-purposes asked 2 years ago.