# Web UI for saving simple named SQL queries

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

We have a proprietary web app that has a flowery admin UI, but poor tools for data geeks.

Our data admin runs many SQL queries to answer business questions - these evolve slowly over time but are run frequently. We'd like for him to have a UI to save and re-run them without having to remote-connect the SQL server multiple times daily or open up saved text snippets.

I'm looking for a small codeproject or similar to save me most of the 2-4 days project work to add this admin feature to my project, which uses the following client/server platform:

- ASP.NET MVC (3-4)
- SQL Server (2008)
- Entity Framework (I'd prefer not to add other data access components for this)
- jQuery

http://sqlfiddle.com/ ( [Ready web query interface to SQL databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213706/ready-web-query-interface-to-sql-databases) ) is kinda what I'm looking for, except 1) it's way overkill, and 2) it doesn't have a UI for naming/saving/loading queries, which is my core requirement.

The tool should:

- Allow textual entering of a previously-composed SQL query in a web browser
- Allow that query to be named and saved
- Allow all saved queries to be listed from a single page
- Allow a saved SQL query to be inspected
- Allow a saved query to be run, with output to a dynamically generated table
- Allow individual saved queries to be deleted
- Possibly enforce a maximum result rows or timeout, just for load-safety
- Possibly prevent data-modification queries

Please let me know if you are aware of any such projects, blog entries, or another related project that makes creating this a no-brainer.

Thank you!

Comment: For the stuff that is run frequently and used to answer business questions, why not parameterize it and develop it into SSRS reports?

Comment: @Kevin : that may be a great option, but I haven't used it before. 

I'm really looking to empower the data admin. Does SSRS require learning significant new semantics or a complex UI? Can my data admin take his existing collection of SQL questions he has saved in text files and paste them right into SSRS, to run on-demand?

When you say "develop it into SSRS reports", it sounds like the same workflow we already have, where a developer adds it to our web application.

Comment: If he is currently using SSMS, then there's a good chance that trying to use anything else will have the opposite effect (re: empower the data admin). There's an awful lot of functionality packed into SSMS - syntax checking, intellisense, query plans, etc. I've tried alternatives to SSMS before, and I have never been satisfied with anything else. If you have an existing reporting solution that you use for recurring 'questions', then reporting services may just be overlapping functionality.

Comment: @Kevin: sounds good to me! No, we don't have a current reporting solution, besides "Oh, you run that query all the time? Let's create a web page for it." Your language made me imagine a possible similar effort to use SSRS. I wonder if we can get SSRS at our web host... we've got a full server with SQL Server. I'm off to do some research. If you want to drop off an answer with your comment, I'll select it if it pans out.

Comment: You could probably use SQL Fiddle as a starting point.  Something you might not be aware on there is that if you are logged in, your "fiddle" history is displayed for each user.  Here you can see queries you've executed recently.  I don't have a name for those yet, but it's something that could easily be added (and I have it on my to-do list).  You can also "Favorite" certain fiddles.  One thing I should mention - the backend code isn't ASP.Net MVC.  It is actually ColdFusion written with an MVC framework.  Should be an easy port, if you wanted to take it on :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to reporting services then it sounds like you could definitely make use of it, as long as you're running it on the same server as the SQL service it's included in the licensing.

It's a fairly robust solution, and has a lot of options for report building, and report delivery. There's a built in interface called the Report Manager, or you can also call the web service directly from your code and deliver back the rendered result in XLS, PDF, DOC and other formats.

You can use either the Report Builder (deployed as a click-once app through the Report Manager interface) or SQL Server Data Tools (older versions are called Business Intelligence Development Studio) for report design.

As I also mentioned, you may find that regardless of all the features in Reporting Services (or SQL Fiddle), your data admin may still want to use SQL Server Management Studio for writing his queries. There's a lot of functionality in SSMS that I know I would have a hard time doing without...