# need sample data for e-commerce class project

Tags: dataset, e-commerce, sample-data

In my CS course project this fall, we have to build a little eCommerce app (like Amazon, eBay, etc).  We are free to build any type of eCommerce/store app.  Since I don't have a preference for what app to build, perhaps it may be easier to decide based on freely available sample data for the store.  So is there some freely available dataset available that represents a set of products, like groceries, movies, books, cars, apps, electronics, weapons, library, etc?  It doesn't have to be real but as long as it can save me a few hours of entering data, it will be worthwhile. An open data format for the dataset would be useful, a MySQL database would be great.

Perhaps I should use the Northwind database from MSSQL?
[Is there a "Northwind" type database available for MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036395/is-there-a-northwind-type-database-available-for-mysql)

I haven't looked at all the reference in this post but it looks promising: [Where can I find sample databases with common formatted data that I can use in multiple database engines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57068/good-databases-with-sample-data)

Any suggestions eCommerce sample datasets?

Comment: I was going to suggest NorthWind as an answer, but you already mention it...

Comment: This question would be on-topic at http://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the nopCommerce sample data. Download from http://nopcommerce.codeplex.com. During installation, tick the "create sample data" box. You can then use the data within your own application. The schema is pretty easy to understand.

Comment: it no longer works any other alternative ?

Answer (score 4):

At this link you can find some e-commerce datasets in Comma-Separated Values format, namely some snapshots of Amazon, Google Products, ABT and Buy.

http://dbs.uni-leipzig.de/en/research/projects/object_matching/fever/benchmark_datasets_for_entity_resolution