# .sql script to load MySQL with sample schema and data?

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a “Northwind” type database available for MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036395/is-there-a-northwind-type-database-available-for-mysql)

Microsoft has the Northwind database to provide a sample database with sample data. I'm aware of how to create a script to do something like this for a MySQL database, but am wondering if such a thing already exists.

I've got a few applications I want to create as a learning exercise for myself.

Is anyone aware of a script for MySQL that will create a sample database(s) and populate it with a good amount of sample data? I'm looking for something with more than just a couple of tables with a couple of rows.

Comment: Hi Michael. For some reason I didn't see that question when I searched. Also searched Google with no luck. When I posted my question I saw this link: [Where can I download sample Mysql database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441062/where-can-i-download-sample-mysql-database?rq=1) also. Thank you for your link as well.

Comment: How do I mark this question as answered? I don't see a way without answering it myself. :-S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL has some sample databases available for learning, most well known are world and sakila.  You can download them at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html.

Comment: Thank you Greg. I wish those sample databases had more fields, but they'll work.